# INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE while installing apps on target getting this error message how to resolve?

Tags: android

want to know is there any architecture wise problem or else ?

Comment: What device are you installing on? Which SDK version does the device have, and what are you targeting? Are you using any native libraries in your app?

Comment: The NDK can be used to generate ARM-based machine code, there is no way it's going to run on an x86 CPU.
There is no support for x86 at the moment simply because there is no officially supported x86 Android system images.
You can refer https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!msg/android-ndk/bx9C1rtUZ_I/tpBLdeIzKigJ.

Comment: If you use intelij idea, just find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958861/install-failed-cpu-abi-incompatible-on-device-using-intellij

Answer (score 3):

An ABI(Application Binary Interface) specifies details that are specific to the machine architecture.
From Wikipedia:

> ABIs cover details such as data type,
>   size, and alignment; the calling
>   convention, which controls how
>   functions' arguments are passed and
>   return values retrieved; the system
>   call numbers and how an application
>   should make system calls to the
>   operating system; and in the case of a
>   complete operating system ABI, the
>   binary format of object files, program
>   libraries and so on.

Found this in the "PackageManager.java" file:

> public static final int INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE = -16;
>
> Installation return code: this is
>   passed to the
>   `IPackageInstallObserver` by
>   `installPackage(android.net.Uri,
>   IPackageInstallObserver, int)` if the
>   package being installed contains
>   native code, but none that is
>   compatible with the the device's
>   CPU_ABI.

Your apk must contain some binary code compiled(using NDK?) for a different machine/emulator while it is being installed on some other machine(emulator).

Answer (score 2):

I saw the reference to this thread in BlueStacks support forum. 
If you are referring to BlueStacks, you will get this error when you try to install an app which has native ARM code and needs binary translation to work on X86 architecture.

This is currently not supported with the alpha release. Please check this link for more details: http://community.bluestacks.com/bluestacks/topics/some_apps_like_angry_birds_fruit_ninja_are_marked_unavailable_on_channels_website_why_is_this_so

[EDIT]: If you any questions related to BlueStacks, please post them on BlueStacks community,
you might also find answers to some common issues(like this one).

Answer (score 1):

i changed avd to target sdk version and it worked fine