# INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE on device using intellij

Tags: android, google-maps, intellij-idea, android-studio

I've seen some questions about this, but none with real answers nor details. Here is my case:

I have an application that uses **Google Maps API v2** which works just fine. Recently I found out that I cannot get it installed on [this](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_razr_i_xt890-4998.php) not ARM-based device.

In order to nail down the problem I'm working with Google Maps samples provided with the SDK (\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples)

which gives me the same error message at install time:

`Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE]`

I get this message only on a real device using Intellij (12.1.1)

It works fine using both Eclipse on real device and using Intellij on the Emulator configured with CPU: Intel Atom (x86)

Any help would be highly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

As expected, same thing happens with Android Studio

Comment: Are there any native libraries in the `libs` folder that are packaged with your application and may be not compatible with the target architecture?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Nope. Besides I'm trying to make it work using only the sample code from Google which I don't believe is platform specific.

Comment: @FuegoFro can u help to find this feature in Android Studio 1.2.2?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

By default, IntelliJ assumes that the `libs` folder in the root of an Android module contains native libraries, even if it just holds jars. Thus, it packages the APK making it look like these are native libraries. I just had a similar issue where my application had no native code and would work on the default emulator, but got the ABI warning when installing on the Genymotion emulator. To fix this, tell IntelliJ (or Android Studio) that your libraries are not native code:

1. Open `File -> Project Structure`.
2. Click `Modules` on the left side of the window.
3. For each Android module, expand the dropdown and select the `Android` subitem.
4. In the `Structure` tab on the right, delete contents of the `Native libs directory` field (you can leave it blank).
5. Once you've done this for each Android module in the project and applied the changes, you may need to rebuild your project for the changes to take place by choosing `Build -> Rebuild Project` from IntelliJ's global menu.

Comment: I think this this a bug in IntelliJ as it assumes you have Native Libraries in your project.  I haven't found an open ticket on the subject so I'll create one.

Comment: Sir, your answer deserves much more than up-votes, why isn't it accepted?! Thanks!

Comment: Agree with @DaleCooper - This is THE answer. Great stuff FuegoFro fixed my problem quickly.

Comment: I don't see Structure tab, only "Sources", "Paths" and "Dependencies". Where is this tab exactly?

Comment: Each Android module in your project (the modules are listed in the second column from the left of the Project Structure window) should be expandable with a small triangle to the left of its name. If you click this triangle you'll see the Android subitem. Once you select this subitem the right-most column/pane should have the Structure tab in it.

Comment: How can do the same from Eclipse editor...any idea/suggestion?

Comment: somehow these menus don't seem to exist in Android Studio anymore, what helped me was installing "ARM Translation Installer" from http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952

Comment: Can you help me find this feature in Android Studio 1.2.2?

Answer (score 12):

Latest Genymotion wont support ARM binary. If you have native code compiled for ARM, you can use the Genymotion-ARM-Translation. Just drag and drop this file to Genymotion home folder and  reboot .

Reference.
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952.

Answer (score 3):

In android studio, Fix this issue:

1 Download Genymotion-ARM-Translation_v1.1.zip

download url:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?s=9f1870536cb530a1346794b6ef629e90&attachmentid=2680937&d=1397258016

2  Drag the zip file into your running virtual device and click ok

3  restart Genymotion virtual device