# Why IntelliJ builds Android APK that is incompatible with x86 architecture

Tags: android, intellij-idea

Further to this post [INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE on device using intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958861/install-failed-cpu-abi-incompatible-on-device-using-intellij) my IntelliJ 12.1.4 builds an Android APK that is incompatible with the Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 10.1 as the CPU architecture for that device is x86 rather than ARM.

I successfully got a build running by building on the command line (`ant clean debug`) and installing the resulting APK via adb.

I'm trying to understand why IntelliJ is building an incompatible APK.  I searched the bug tracker and couldn't find an existing bug so I'm also wondering how many people are also having this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [INSTALL\_FAILED\_CPU\_ABI\_INCOMPATIBLE on device using intellij](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958861/install-failed-cpu-abi-incompatible-on-device-using-intellij)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this issue, check out my answer for the referenced question:

[INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE on device using intellij](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20185696/3000133)