# Cannot run android application on Intel x86 device using android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-x86

I have recently migrated to Android studio from Eclipse,The problem which i am facing is that i cannot run my application on my device which is Asus Zenfone 5 with Intel x86 Atom processor,When i try to run the code i get the following error like:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE]
```

The code does not contain any Platform specific libraries AFAIK i've refered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20185696/2636887) but i cannot find the options in the new android studio project structures,

How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: I've asked the question because the existing answers are outdated,love to know the reason for down voting or at least tell me how can i improve the question

Comment: Seems like a worthy question...  In my opinion, the hardest part of learning Android is just getting the tools to work (and devices to be recognized). Have you tried building a simple "hello world" app to validate if it runs on your device?

Comment: yes,actually this is a hello world application

Comment: Does "adb shell" from the command prompt work?  Also, have you tried just plan "adb install yourapp.apk" as well?

Comment: Open your apk with zip file tools and see if it has anything erroneously claiming to be a libraries folder.

Comment: @ChrisStratton no there's no other libraries other than apache commons io that i've added

Comment: @selbie the same error is produced while installing manually over adb

Comment: That's not what I asked.  Check the zip file structure of tbe apk.  Java libraries should not survive as distinct entities in the apk.

Comment: I opened the apk file from the build folder in winrar and went to the libs folder and I could  only find the apache-commons-io jar file which i've added earlier,is there something wrong with that?

Comment: There should be no jars in a libs folder, rather they get merged with your code into the dex. You have misapplied the jar to the project.

Comment: then how do i resolve this?,removing the dependency won't fix the problem i think?

Comment: Actually,it did after removing the dependency  and a rebuild ,Thank you Chris for pointing it out.