# INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE on Bluestacks

Tags: android, android-studio, bluestacks

I am trying to get my app working on Bluestacks.
Using Android Studio Emulator and real Android Devices I experienced no problems, but when I try to install the .apk on [Bluestacks Emulator](http://www.bluestacks.com/local/deu/home-deu.html) I get the error message: "INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE"

I tried the accepted answer on [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958861/install-failed-cpu-abi-incompatible-on-device-using-intellij), but as already pointed out there in the comments this solution is for Intellij and although Android Studio is similar to Intellij, the tab mentioned in the solution does not exist in Android Studio.

With this and the few other results on google I narrowed my problem down to the fact that th error message means I'm using (or the apk thinks I'm using) native code.

But I think I can rule that out for my own code and I also don't think that my third party libraries (see following list) include native code. Or do they? I'm not sure how to determine this.

My Dependencies:

```
 ical4j-1.0.6.jar
 commons-net-3.3.jar
 commons-lang-2.6.jar
 org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.1
 commons-logging:commons-logging:1.2
 org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:1.8
 backport-util-concurrent:backport-util-concurrent:3.1
 com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87
 com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar
 com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.3
 com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1
 org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2
 com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3
```

Maybe there's some other cause?

I would appreciate try out any thoughts and suggestions so feel free to answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the apache commons codec library.

I examined the .apk file and found the codec library as a .jar in it.
All other libraries except that one were unpacked.
I assume in the repository, where I got it from via Maven, the .jar is packaged in another .jar.

Using another repository of the library produced a file without the .jar and worked on bluestacks (As mentioned above it already worked on other platforms before).