# I have an issue with my dependencies... INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE

Tags: android, build, installation, incompatibletypeerror

I have made an application which work perfectly on a tablet. But with another tablet, if I try to run my application, I can't : I have an error : "INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE"

I have looked on internet to understand the problem, but I have some difficulties to understand(it's something about processor and librairies).

What I have found it's if I delete a dependencie, I can build the app.
As you can see:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

 android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "ime.projet"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
}
```

I have two dependencies but if I delete "compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'" it works perfectly so Is somebody can explain to me why there is a problem with that? And how is it possible to correct it? (because I need this dependencie for some functions)...

Thank you for your help !

Comment: This question answered. Please visit this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958861/install-failed-cpu-abi-incompatible-on-device-using-intellij

Comment: Yes I have already see that, thank you for your help but I don't understand because in my Project structure, I don't find any librairies so I can't try his answer..
Just two precision if it can help: I am a beginner so sorry if my question is quite simple and I work with Android Studio as IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the apache commons-io to 2.6, it will work