# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE] Cocos2D-x V3 Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

I have just made the installation and Setup from Cocos2D-x V3. I create and compile the project as it says in the tutorial for Android Studio but when I try to run it it throw:

```
10/11 18:37:45: Launching Example
$ adb push /Users/Matias/Desktop/Example/proj.android-studio/app/build/outputs/apk/Example-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/trabajoPractico1.cococos2dx.Example
**$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/trabajoPractico1.cococos2dx.Example"
    pkg: /data/local/tmp/trabajoPractico1.cococos2dx.Example
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE]**


$ adb shell pm uninstall trabajoPractico1.cococos2dx.Example
**Unknown failure (Failure)
Error while Installing APK**
```

**I try running it in Genymotion and AVD**

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15958861/install-failed-cpu-abi-incompatible-on-device-using-intellij

Comment: @T-he-game It could be but i don't find the subitem Android neither the dropdown icon. Here you have a screenshot https://ibb.co/d56EVb

Comment: Fair enough. What is your Compile Sdk Version? Your's says unrecognized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Android Studio

Cocos2d-x now have full support for **Android Studio**. This answer is for Android Studio using cocos2d-x version 3.16.

After you create the project you can find the folder called **"proj.android-studio"** inside this folder you can find the file "**gradle.properties**"
you will need to change this line of the code.

```graddle
PROP_APP_ABI=armeabi
```

for this

```graddle
PROP_APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a:x86
```

I'm not sure why the default template is only for support armeabi.
But you can edit the template just locate the folder 
"**cpp-template-default\proj.android-studio**" and edit the graddle-properties so when you create a new project it will be ready for your new projects.

### Eclipse Project.

Most of cocos2d-x project I guess they still uses Eclispe so in this case is more easy just change **Application.mk**

just replace

```
APP_ABI := armeabi
```

with

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
```

Answer (score 2):

It means the apk you're building has native C or C++ libraries that aren't compiled for the correct CPU.  Generally devices need ARM or ARM-v7.  Simulators need x86 or x86-64.  If the right one isn't available, you won't install (and if somehow you do, you'll break when you try to load the library).

Comment: so how can i fix it?

Comment: Find the right abi libraries.  If you're on a simulator, try both x86 and x86-64 images.